# Give higher priority to specific ranges in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is a sample document from my index

```
{
"name" : "Neil Buckinson",
"insuranceType" : "personal",
"premiumAmount": 4000,
"age": 36
}
```

I want to give the documents with premium amount 3500 to 4500 more priority than others. How can I do that in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say a better approach would be function score query with filter functions -

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "weight": 100,
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "premiumAmount": {
                "gte": 3500,
                "lte": 4500
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple. Just use [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and add your condition in `should` clause.

> The `bool` query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score
>   from each matching `must` or `should` clause will be added together to
>   provide the final `_score` for each document.

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "premiumAmount": {
              "gte": 3500,
              "lte": 4500
            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Just place your current query in `must` clause instead of `match_all`.

`should` means that this condition is optional, but if it matches your criterion, it will boost your document 
That's what exactly you're looking for.